# Implied property of type Object in C# - is it possible?

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics

I'm trying to convert the following function from VB to C#:

```
Private Function CheckHeader(ByVal Request As Object, ByRef Response As Object) As Boolean
  CheckHeader = True
  If Request.Header Is Nothing Then
     CheckHeader = False
     Throw New System.ArgumentException("Header Object not found")
  End If
End Function
```

And here is what I have so far in C#:

```
private bool CheckHeader(object Request, ref object Response)
  {
     bool functionReturnValue = false;
     functionReturnValue = true;

     var localRequest = Request;

     if (localRequest.Header == null)
     {
        functionReturnValue = false;
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Header Object not found");
     }
     return functionReturnValue;
  }
```

The problem is with the Request parameter that is of type Object.  In VB, we have the nice feature of the implied property, which of course C# doesn't like one bit. Any object that does get passed as the "Request" parameter is supposed to have the Header parameter.  I'm just checking to see if it's there. I'm thinking the use of generics might apply here, but I'm unsure of the route to take.  Any ideas?

Comment: That completely depends on how you're calling it.

Comment: The error I'm currently encountering is the following on the localRequest.Header == null line:  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Header' and no extension method 'Header' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found.  Is there a way in C# to imply that I do have a Header property on something that is of type Object?

Comment: There is no `Header` property for the `System.Object` type.  The VB code relies on *late binding* to run (and is error prone) and wont compile using Option Strict

Comment: Strange that `Response` is never changed in this method...

Comment: And there is no point in assigning a return value if you're just going to throw...

Answer (score 4):

only way I can think for you to do the same thing in c# is to use the [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) keyword

it should behave like the strict off of vb.net

```
    private bool CheckHeader(dynamic Request, ref object Response)
    {
        bool functionReturnValue = false;
        functionReturnValue = true; //you should put true above instead

        var localRequest = Request; //not sure why this but whatever

        if (localRequest.Header == null)
        {
            functionReturnValue = false; //no need for this here, because of the throw
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Header Object not found");
        }
        return functionReturnValue; //at this point remove 
                                    //this variable and simply return true
    }
```

so this should be ok

```
    private bool CheckHeader(dynamic Request, ref object Response)
    {
        //Response variable should stay there since it might be a
        //breaking change, you should check if you can remove it

        if (Request.Header == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Header Object not found");
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @CurlyShuffle if this really is the whole function, there is no point in creating `functionReturnValue`. just return `true` at the end, since the `false` value is lost when we `throw`

Answer (score 0):

Because `object` has no `Header` property, if possible I would convert `Request Object` into a `c#` `interface`.  So I would change the code to look like this:

First `IRequest` `interface`:

```
public interface IRequest
{
    //Assuming Header is an object.
    MyHeaderObject Header {get;set;}
}
```

Now `CheckHeader` function:

```
private bool CheckHeader(IRequest Request, ref object Response)
{
    bool functionReturnValue = false;
    functionReturnValue = true;

    var localRequest = Request;

    if (localRequest.Header == null)
    {
       functionReturnValue = false;
       throw new System.ArgumentException("Header Object not found");
    }
    return functionReturnValue;
}
```

Now everything that passes a `Request` to `CheckHeader` needs to implement `IRequest`.

Here is an example of it:

```
public MyRequest : IRequest 
{
   public MyHeaderObject Header {get;set;}
}
```